# How to log the real client IP on embedded Tomcat access log on Spring Boot application with Nginx as reverse proxy?

Tags: spring, tomcat, nginx, spring-boot, http-headers

I have Nginx in front of a Spring Boot 1.3.3 application with Tomcat access log enabled, but the logging always write the proxy IP address (127.0.0.1) instead of the real client IP.

1. Is the X-Real-IP header used to get the real client IP?
2. Is this header used by tomcat to write the IP address in the access log?

I have this configuration:

application.properties

```
server.use-forward-headers=true
server.tomcat.internal-proxies=127\\.0\\.0\\.1
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
```

Nginx configuration:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8091;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

Comment: No generally the `X-Forwared-For` one. Are you also using an external client or are you calling it from the same server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The real client IP is available in `$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for` variable i.e. `X-Forwarded-For` header. It will have "," separated entries. The very first value is the real client IP.

To log the real client IP in Tomcat's access logs, modify the pattern value in the AccessLog Valve as:

```
%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t "%r" %s %b
```

Comment: Thank you @nidhi! It worked! Now I have the client IP. I found on the documentation that this %{...}i get the value from headers. Thank you

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks