# Tomcat: 'X-Forwarded-For' doesn't work with load balancer

Tags: tomcat, proxy, tomcat7, load-balancing, x-forwarded-for

We are currently working on a redundant server setup (2 servers + 1 load balancer) using Tomcat 7 update 76. To fulfill the logging requirements of our company, we are trying to get the IP of the remote server, that actually sends the request, not the IP of the load balancer. Unfortunately we were not able to get it to work with the following documentation:

- https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteIpValve.html
- https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/AccessLogValve.html
- https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_IP_Valve

We used the following configuration for access logging and remote valve:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" internalProxies="xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.7|xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.8|xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.9"  remoteIpHeader="X-Forwarded-For" />
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
prefix="access_log." suffix=".log"
pattern="%{org.apache.catalina.AccessLog.RemoteAddr}r %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" 
requestAttributesEnabled="true" />
```

The request header 'X-Forwarded-For' was set and load balancer was analyzed via wireshark. However we still only get the IP of the load balancer and not the IP of the remote client. The IP adresses of the config have already been checked and they are correct.

Comment: what load-balancer are you using ? It may be configured to not insert the XFF header

Comment: The load balancer was tested with wireshark and shows the corresponding header field. It's difficult to look further into the configuration of the load balancer because it's managed by another provider.

Comment: Use [Request Dumper Filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Request_Dumper_Filter) to see what Tomcat receives, it will answer if the LB is sending the XFF header or not. There are other ways to debug btw, I'm just giving an idea.

Comment: We enabled the Request Dumper Filter now. The requests from the load balancer include the following line: header=x-forwarded-for=yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy.

Comment: You can try increasing the log level of `org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.level` to `FINE` in `logging.properties`

Answer (score 0):

Changing the pattern of the AccessLogValve was the solution for me, like so :

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
pattern="%{x-forwarded-for}i %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36357291/1830268

full pattern attribute options are here : https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve/Attributes

Comment: That is unfortunately a half-solution: what the OP tries to achieve isn't limited to pretty logs. [`ServletRequest#getRemoteAddr`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/servlet/servletrequest#getRemoteAddr--) must return the IP of the real client for other important valves like [`RemoteAddrValve`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_Address_Valve) to work correctly. If the `RemoteIpValve` works correctly, the pattern in the question must also work.

Comment: In my case, and as I understand the OP's question, the RemoteIpValve works correctly, i.e calls to getRemoteAddress are correctly reporting the real remote IP, but the %h attribute in the accessLog pattern still returns the Proxy IP instead of the remote client IP. Changing %h with %{x-forwarded-for}i  fixed the IP logged in the access logs in my case. The way I understood the OP's question it was the same problem as me.

Comment: `AccessLogValve` is called after `RemoteIpValve` has changed the remote address forth and **back**. That's why `%h` doesn't work **unless** you also use `requestAttributesEnabled="true"` (as the OP did) in which case the remote address is taken from the request attributes (precisely `org.apache.catalina.AccessLog.RemoteAddr`) instead of the request itself.

Comment: Thank you, I had missed the requestAttributesEnabled option, and it's helpful in my case.